# Find starting character(s) and special characters in a String

Tags: regex, string

I am new to RegEx and need to come up with a RegEx that will find matching character(s) in a String.

The possible strings that I could get are:

```
DFG-2344KG
4GGRTE/345
9TTRRE-547
7TTRRE-547
T89FGFGD+9
```

So what I want is a RegEx that will check to see if the string starts with **DFG** or **4** or **7** or **T** AND it does only have "**-**" for special characters other than alphanumeric characters.

So from the above list of strings, only **9TTRRE-547** will be a valid string.

I am looking for a RegEx that can do that for me. So far I came up with:

^(DFG|T|4|7)

The above RegEx correctly finds the invalid starting character(s). Now the challenge is finding a special character other than "-" that can happen anywhere in the string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess I'm confused about your example. Why would 9TTRE-547 be a valid string and DFG-2344KG not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with:

```
^(DFG|4|7|T)[A-Z0-9-]+$
```

It is exactly what you have so far together with `[A-Z0-9-]+` to indicate: "any alpha numeric character or `-`. By saying `+` we mean that it occur one or many times.

Then, `$` to indicate end of line.

You can see it working in https://regex101.com/r/mX5kV8/1 with these matches:

```
DFG-2344KG
7TTRRE-547
7TTRRE547
```

Comment: Don't forget to anchor the end. Also, it would be good to point out that this is ERE, and that the expression would look different in BRE.

Comment: @ghoti good point, edited with `$`! Regarding ERE/BRE, honestly I don't know the insights so I just believe you it is ERE.